# Is therey any way to automate user adding into keycloak groups?

Tags: keycloak

I am planning to give user access programmatically. So, I want to add users to keycloak groups. Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: when do you want to do that? for all currently available users? when new users are registered?, ...

Answer (score 4):

You can define some groups as default groups, then they will be added to any created users automatically. You can do this in the admin console.